# jQuery selectors does not recognize ny dynamically created HTML input function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am injecting HTMl code into the dom using Ajax. It does this sucessfully but my jQuery selector does not work for this HTML input

So if i do the following in my Jquery it does not get recognized...

```
$("input[id*='cb_Compare']").click(function ()
```

However if i assign the input with an onclick function in my server side code thatworks.

What is this sorcery?

Comment: did you try $(selector).on('click', function () { ... }); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are generating HTML dynamically with jQuery so you have to use **event delegation** in order to bind the `click()` event as shown :-

```
$(document.body).on('click','input[id*="cb_Compare"]',function(){
  //...your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If the DOM is added dynamically, you need to use event delegation. Read this link for further understanding. [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click',"input[id*='cb_Compare']",function (){
  //your code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **event delegation** with immediate parent selector is best way to do dynamically created elements

```
$("#parentSelector").on("click", "input[id*='cb_Compare']" , function() { 

          // your code here
});
```

or

```
$(document).on("click", "input[id*='cb_Compare']" , function() { 

              // your code here
    });
```